# How to sort an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, networkx, adjacency-matrix

Is there a way in Python to "sort" an adjacency matrix in order to better see the different clusters of connected nodes?

I have some matrix yet, but patterns looks like randomly distributed on it. In the real world I know for example I have N independent clusters (no connexions in between).

So I want the adjacency matrix to look like there is N distinct patterns.

Is this achievable?

**Update:**
I hadn't the time yesterday but here is now some details:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
S = {'7064', '7065', '7066', '7067', '7068', '7069', '7070', '7071', '7072', '7073', '7074', '7075', '7076', '7077', '7078', '7079', '7080'}
E = [('7064', '7065'),
('7067', '7068'),
('7067', '7076'),
('7067', '7077'),
('7067', '7078'),
('7067', '7079'),
('7067', '7080'),
('7067', '7081'),
('7068', '7076'),
('7068', '7077'),
('7068', '7078'),
('7068', '7080'),
('7068', '7081'),
('7069', '7075'),
('7070', '7072'),
('7070', '7074'),   
('7071', '7074'),
('7076', '7077'),
('7076', '7078'),
('7076', '7079'),
('7076', '7080'),
('7076', '7081'),
('7077', '7078'),
('7077', '7079'),
('7077', '7080'),
('7077', '7081'),
('7078', '7079'),
('7078', '7080'),
('7078', '7081'),
('7079', '7080'),
('7079', '7081'),
('7080', '7081')]
G.add_nodes_from(S)
G.add_edges_from(E)
adj_matrix = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).toarray()

plt.imshow(adj_matrix)
```

[image: adjacency matrix]

In facts, I only care for the upper triangle as it's a symmetric matrix (samples vs themselves).

```
sub_graphs   = list(nx.connected_components(G))
nb_clusters  = len(sub_graphs) # total number of sub graphs, including isolated points, there is here 2 isolated points. All other are at least linked with min 1 other point.
```

I'd like the adjacency matrix to look like there is 6 "blobs" (two of them will be single pixel for the two isolated points). Currently, it displays in its upper triangle, 12 visually separated area (they are only separated visually, in fact the matrix is OK but I'd like to rearrange it to be more suited to the number of sub graphs reality)

Comment: How is the adjacency matrix represented in your code? Can you show some code you are using?

Comment: main post edited.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be already answered in [Hierarchical clustering of heatmap in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430742/hierarchical-clustering-of-heatmap-in-python) , however, there is no accepted answer.

The answer is to cluster the rows and columns of the heatmap for similarity (e.g. Euclidean distance), just like seaborn can do automatically for you http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html .
An adjacency matrix is just a special case of a regular matrix seaborn can use, where elements are either 0 or 1.